# is there any way to handle "ALT" key in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

is there any way to handle "ALT" key in flex? When I press alt ley the KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN event is not fired and focus moves to browser's main menu(IE, Opera, Firefox)

Answer (score 2):

If the KeyboardEvent is fired there is the KeyboardEvent.altKey (Boolean), which indicates if the alt key is pressed.
see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#altKey

But if the alt key doesn't fire the KeyboardEvent, maybe JavaScript is an option, but I don't know if JavaScript could handle this.